# I want to install Gnome on kubuntu 14.04 is it safe?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, kubuntu

I'm new to linux and exploring diffrent things. Anyway. If I installed Gnome on my kubuntu 14.04 will Gnome remove or replace the packages I installed?

Answer (score 0):

As a new Ubuntu user, it's probably better to make a new partition where you can install Ubuntu Gnome, assuming you have the space. Otherwise, you are likely to face a system that, while not technically broken, still frustrates you in several ways.

You may also want to make an additional partition where you can test out the combination. You can always delete it and reclaim the space later if you work out any resulting problems from combining the two desktops.

Most noticeable will the fact that the `alternatives` system will change the default boot splash screens and login greeter to the Gnome versions. These can easily be changed back, however. You can find several answers about this point on the site.

You will also end up with additional programs installed to handle common functions, such as video playback or media burning. This is not a problem beyond disk space or cluttered menus, but I've seen a lot of questions where people complain about this.

More problematic, however, will be the possibility of subtle conflicts among various desktop and UI elements that affect behavior or the look and feel. Some of these, such as the look of `gtk` programs under `kde` are often easily fixed by installing certain packages and changing some settings. Others, however, are harder to pin down and remain the subject of various unanswered questions.

I don't want to veer off into opinion, but it seems safe to say that as the different desktop environments advance, the incompatibilities are growing.

Installing Gnome should not literally remove anything that you already have installed. This would only happen if there were packages to be installed that are in conflict with existing packages. I'm not aware of any conflicts at this level. Plus, if that were to happen, the package manager would warn you and give you the chance to abort the installation.